# Cannot find silverlight Busy Indicator Control in Choose Items ToolBox Window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml

I have Installed the Silverlight 5 SDK and I am Trying to Add silverlight  Busy Indicator Control to my ToolBox.But I cant Find it in Choose Items ToolBox Window

[image]

How Can I Add silverlight  Busy Indicator Control to my ToolBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BusyIndicator exist in the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit assembly. You must download and install Silverlight 5 Toolkit. After that BusyIndicator must be appeared in ToolBox Window.
Also you can get source codes of Toolkit components.

[**Silverlight 5 Toolkit download link**](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435)

**[Here is the direct link to source code](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/35261#777793)**

Answer (score 3):

The Busy Indicator is in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), not the default Silverlight 5 SDK.

If you download, install, and reference that in your project, you will be able to access `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.BusyIndicator`.

[Download Silverlight 5 Toolkit here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/downloads/get/311823).